# Export XY Coordinates for object in Flash

Tags: xml, flash, export

I have a Flash project that I would like to export the coordinates of an object from.

Ideally, I would like the position of the object for each frame in the animation.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the flash source files, the simplest solution would be to add the following code to the first frame of your application.

(Assuming `objectToTrack` is the name of the movieclip you want the coordinates from)

```
this.addEventListener( Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame );

function onEnterFrame ( e:Event ):void {
    trace ( "x : " + objectToTrack.x + ", y : " + objectToTrack.y );
}
```